# Elastic Search Statistical Facets - Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, facet, nest

So I have an index containing a 82 documents like the following (sample data to familiarise me with the api).

```
{"_index":"foo","_type":"bar","_id":"3675293","_score":1.0, "_source" : {
  "companyId": 3675293,
  "companyName": "ABC",
  "companyOwner": {
    "ownerFirstName": "Billy",
    "ownerLastName": "Jean"
  },
  "created": "2013-05-22T13:45:49",
  "accounts": [
    {
      "year": 2013,
      "amount": 1.0,
      "currency": "GBP"
    },
    {
      "year": 2012,
      "amount": 1.0,
      "currency": "GBP"
    }
  ]
}}
```

The problem I have is that I'm trying to total all of the amounts. When I use a Statistical Facet via the NEST .Net client I get an answer I wouldn't expect.

82 documents, each with a collection containing 2 amount of £1 in my mind aggregates to a total of 2 X 82 = 164. However, the facet returns a total of 82. When I change one of the amounts in each of the two documents to be 2 instead of 1, I get the correct result.

Does Elastic Search only aggregate unique numerical values per document? Can this be overriden?

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question on the google group for Elastic Search. Question and response here.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/wNjrnAC_KOY

Comment: Would be nice to post at least an excerpt of what the solution is in your own answer and auto accept it. ;)